# Accessing object-type methods from an object array java

Tags: java, arrays

My problem is I'm trying to make a console based chess game. Starting off with an Object array to hold the squares of the chess board.

```
class Chessboard {
    Object[][] board = new Object[10][10];
```

I fill it out perfectly with various if-sentences like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j < 10; j++) {
        if a position on a chess demands a specific piece:
                 board[i][j] = new ChessPiece(String firstLetterOfPiece, i, j);
        else fill in blanks:
                 board[i][j] = new ChessPiece(" ", i,j);
    }
}
```

Now, I have some find position methods in the `ChessPiece` class that just gives a compiler error when I try it from the class Chessboard.

What I do is: (to test)

```
System.out.println(board[2][4].getXposition());
```

I get "Cannot find symbol".
What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Post the exact message: what symbol can't it find? What's that extraneous `String` doing in your pseudocode in the `new ChessPiece` ctor call?

Comment: Why can't you use `ChessPiece[][] board = new ChessBoard[10][10]`? And why are you using a 10x10 grid? A "moat" doesn't make a lot of sense here.

Comment: Can't find method getXpos(). Because java looks in Object-class. The string is to identify the chesspiece. Also, I believe that using a Objectarray I can mix different classes which is a bit easier when it comes to displaying integers and letters. (The sides, top and bottom of the chessboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could "cast" it, for example: `((ChessPiece)(board[2][4])).getXposition()`

But I would recommend doing something different: make a ChessSquare class that can hold a ChessPiece, or not.

Then go

```
ChessSquare square = board[2][4];
if(square.hasPiece()) {
    ChessPiece piece = square.getPiece();
    return piece.getXposition();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your array will only ever contain ChessPiece objects, declare it as

```
ChessPiece[][] board = new ChessPiece[10][10];
```

Secondly, since your array elements can be null, you'll want to do a null check before calling any methods:

```
if(board[2][4] != null)  System.out.println(board[2][4].getXPosition());
```

Comment: Thanks, though I throw in some integers and strings to display a through h and 1 through 8. :)